# Using GoogleAnalytics to keep track of sessions

Tags: google-analytics

It it possible to use GoogleAnalytics to keep track of individual user sessions? I mean, not the average time spend by users on the website, but how long did each user stay in total on the website?

My hosting option does not include databases, so I'd like to use GoogleAnalytics to keep track of user sessions. Can it be done? I was unable to find anything satisfying on the web. :(

Comment: @Colin I already placed the GA code on my website, but I can't find anywhere on the dashboard what I'm looking for. Only the average time spent by users. That's it. I'd like a list with all the users and their individual times. Do you have any idea how to get that?

Comment: @Colin they obviously track individual times for each user in order to calculate the average time, but how can I access that information?

Comment: I want to know exactly which users stayed more than 5 or 10 seconds on my website and remove the rest from the total. So the ones that just entered the website and then closed it, I want to ignore them in this sum and only get the number of those who stayed more than 5-10 secs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not really - Google Analytics doesn't track on a per user basis (because that's actually quite useless, among other things).

You could do a workaround, however. Assign each visitor an id (or pull the user id from the analytics cookie via javascript). Then trigger a E-Commerce-Transaction with the id as transaction id and the time on site (use the timestamps from the GA cookie) as transaction value - Google will add up transaction values if the transaction id is the same. This idea is untested and obviously needs some work, but it should be doable.

Which leaves the question , why ? What kind of business decision do you want to base on a vast list of useless info ? The average values are much more useful.

**Update:** after reading your comment, you're doing it wrong. You want an advanced segment-> Exclude Visit Duration smaller (or greater, whatever) than 10 seconds.

Comment: Please see the comment my last comment on the post above. I've explained myself there.

Comment: Oh God ... can it be THAT simple? :)) Let me check...

Comment: hahaha ... that's it ! Thanks. Now I feel like an idiot.

Comment: No need to feel like an idiot, but it's always better to explain your intented outcome instead of your attempts at a solution - answers will be quicker and better that way.

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics does not allow you to track individual users.

See this thread: 
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/tTaqssN7sY8

Try out Woopra: http://www.woopra.com/

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to filter by [advanced segments](http://www.google.com.au/analytics/features/advanced-segments.html) or use [custom reports](http://www.google.com.au/analytics/features/custom-reports.html) to do your own filtering. Or  create a [custom metric](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2709828) that itself is filtered.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was looking for. Unfortunately I can only accept one answer and Eike answered first. Thank you very much for your time though :(

Comment: You probably want to filter by https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/session#ga:visitLength